# Creating provisioning profiles for using with TestFlight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to get my app to work with [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) by following [this](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413) article on their website. At step 5 when it says to select your Development Provisioning Profile and Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile, I'm not sure what to do:

> Go to the Build Settings tab and scroll down to the Code Signing
>   section. For the two default build configurations (Debug and Release),
>   select your Development Provisioning Profile for Debug and your Ad Hoc
>   Provisioning Profile for Release. Leave Code Signing Entitlements
>   blank.

How do I create these? The whole provisioning profile thing is so confusing. For my phone I just clicked "Use for development" or whatever and it basically worked to test my app on. Do I have to create something different?

(Yes I'm a registered developer.)

Comment: Spend several hours studying Apple's official documentation (testflight glosses over important details). It will save you time in the long run. Also learn how testflight works. It doesn't do anything complicated, just puts a nice interface on something you could slap together yourself in a few hours. Once you understand it, it won't be confusing. :-) There are also bugs in Xcode, which are easier to workaround if you know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the words of encouragement. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create provisioning profiles for adhoc and distribution.
See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html
Under 'create an AdHoc provisioning profile'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to create a Distribution and Development profiles. This is done on http://developer.apple.com/ ...follow the most updated how-to's appl provides or RECENT online tutorials and go for it.

The process used to be incredibly confusing, but has gotten much simpler over the past few years, don't be scared by all the old things your read. Also, many common tasks like renewing profiles are now autmomated in the XCODE organizer. However, creating these in the first place is done using the dev website and Keychain Access.

You may still struggle a bit to get going the first time, but knowing how to work with provisioning is essential if you want to test/share/distribute/sell your apps.

Comment: What did I create provisioning profile wise with clicking "Use this device for development"? Didn't I create a provisioning profile in Xcode with that?

Comment: I am not positive, without seeing, but what you probably did was add your device to your apple dev account. I promise, what you need is a guided tour through the provisioning process via the latest Apple Documents/How-To's. It's important to do all the steps in the right order, so please do start from the beginning, following the instructions carefully.